# Button over tableviewcontroller stretching (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, tableview

I have a button in a view which is in the footer of a tableview (UITableViewController). Why is the button stretching when I try to apply the following code to it?

[image]

And I apply the code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Make footerview so it fill up size of the screen
   // The button is aligned to bottom of the footerview 
   // using autolayout constraints
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil
    self.footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.footerView.frame.size.height)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.footerView
}
```

I was following the answer on this question:

[Add button on top of UITableViewController (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391407/add-button-on-top-of-uitableviewcontroller-swift)

Thanks!

Comment: Add a height constraint to your button

Answer (score 0):

If you read the question (whose link you posted) carefully, you can see that he resizes the view to take up the rest of the screen that is remaining after your table. Your button is the same size as your view, that is why it is stretching up. You need to add constraints which bind your button to the bottom of the view but not the top. Because if you bind the top and the bottom both to the view it will stretch.
Here is the example.
1. When you do not bind the button to the top. Notice that in the constraints, I do not have any constraint that specify the top of the button.

[image]

2. When you bind your button to the the top of the view. In this, I set a constraint which bind the button top to the view top. It stretches my button to take up the whole space as the view(which is similar to your case)

[image]

Hope this helps. :)